# Facebook like of wordpress content as iFrame in CMS

Tags: facebook, iframe, share, facebook-like

I have a wordpress blog inside a CMS of an institution! I cannot change that.
The wordpress-blog is implemented as an iFrame in the CMS.
I tried a few wordpress plugins for social media inlcuding facebook likes. But unfortunatly facebook is not finding the content of the blogpost!
Sometimes it takes the content and the pictures of the blogpost, sometimes it just takes a picture of the CMS and sometimes it just posts the link. Especially if i want to share it by hand by "posting" the blogpost of wordpress in facebook.

Is there any possibility to let facebook manually know where the relevant content is (maybe by div-id or something?)